# Store the given text field value into particular database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am doing small project using android database to store a particular text field value into given server ip address. I gone through many sites for storing the given data into database. But they are all stored inside system and we can view that by using DDMS. But i want to store the given text field value into particular server(using an server ip address to access a server).How Can i do this. can some one give me the solution. Please, sorry for my bad english friends.

Comment: What exactly it does mean store a string into server ip ?, Do you mean there is a server (obviously with an IP address) which you want to store a string value into it ? based on network protocols HTTP(S), FTP, ... it is possible but it depends on protocol and structure of job you want to do, there are a web service solution too (Http protocol), I am sorry but it is weird question to me ?, please make it clear what exactly you want to do ...

Comment: ya just want to store a given string values into one database.througn any one of the protocols. @H-Bahrami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Web server create a database,  you need to use php for communication of database and your data storage request.  Also you need to retrieve data so you need to use Json and implement it in Android.

For example for this purpose  go to Androidhive . Info and check the example given there.